# PigStorage multibyte field separator

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Needed a StoreFunc implementation that could allow PIG to have field delimiters as multiple bytes for example - ^^ (\u005E\u005E)

Tried all these but without succcess -

```
store B into '/tmp/test/output'  using PigStorage('\u005E\u005E');
store B into '/tmp/test/output'  using PigStorage('^^');
store B into '/tmp/test/output'  using PigStorage('\\^\\^');
```

Is there an already existing implementation like LoadFunc implementation  `org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MyRegExLoader` for StoreFunc that can take regular expressions for field separator while writing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked around this by using CONCAT for first delimiter and using PigStorage syntax for second occurence